# JS - Delete every object of the same type

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas, javascript-objects

Hi I'm coding a canvas game as a school project and I've created a constructor for a "button" object like this:

```
// button object constructor

function button(xL, xR, yT, yB) {
    this.xLeft = xL;
    this.xRight = xR;
    this.yTop = yT;
    this.yBottom = yB;
    this.width = xR - xL;
    this.height = yB - yT;
    this.drawMe = function() {
        neonWariorPlayArea.context.strokeStyle = "blue";
        neonWariorPlayArea.context.beginPath();
        neonWariorPlayArea.context.rect(this.xLeft, this.yTop, this.width, this.height);
        neonWariorPlayArea.context.stroke();
    }
}

button.prototype.clicked = function() {
    if (this.xLeft <= mouseX && mouseX <= this.xRight && this.yTop <= mouseY && mouseY <= this.yBottom) {
        return true;

    }
}
```

Now I'm facing a problem that I don't know how to approach and that is how to remove every button already created? I need this because when I change a screen (for example from the main menu to character creator) buttons are still present and clickable. 
I was trying to create some sort of an array in which I would hold all the buttons objects and then loop through that array deleting every element of an array.

```
var buttons = new Array();

playBtn = new button(500, 650, 50, 100);
tutorialBtn = new button(500, 760, 110, 160);
scoreBtn = new button(500, 670, 180, 230);

buttons.push(playBtn, tutorialBtn, scoreBtn);

function deleteBtns() {
    buttons.forEach(iterate);
}

function iterate(item, index) {
    console.log(index);
    delete buttons[index];
}
```

Now I've come to the point where I'm out of ideas and my google-fu isn't strong enough. Thank you for help or advice.

Comment: Doesn't `buttons = []` work?

Answer (score 1):

You can `.filter` button to eliminate button not needed, and reassign to array.

Deleting all you can do by assigning `blank array`:  `buttons = []`

To get a unique button, you can create a unique function.

```
function unique(buttons) {
  let set = new Set();
  let filtedBtns = [];
  buttons.forEach((btn) => {
    if (!set.has(btn.toString())) {
      filtedBtns.push(btn);
      set.add(btn.toString());
    }
  });
  return filtedBtns;
}
```

```js
var buttons = new Array();
function button(x, y, a, b) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.toString = () => {
    return `${x}::${y}::${a}::${b}`;
  };
}

playBtn = new button(500, 650, 50, 100);
tutorialBtn = new button(500, 760, 110, 160);
duplicateBtn = new button(500, 760, 110, 160);
scoreBtn = new button(500, 670, 180, 230);

buttons.push(playBtn, tutorialBtn, duplicateBtn, scoreBtn);
function unique() {
  let set = new Set();
  let filtedBtns = [];
  buttons.forEach((btn) => {
    if (!set.has(btn.toString())) {
      filtedBtns.push(btn);
      set.add(btn.toString());
    }
  });
  return filtedBtns;
}

function deleteBtns(index) {
  buttons = buttons.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
}
function deleteAll() {
  buttons = [];
}
console.log(buttons);
deleteBtns(1);
buttons = unique(buttons)
console.log(buttons);

deleteBtns(1);
console.log(buttons);
deleteAll();
console.log(buttons);
```

**Class-based approach:**

```js
class Button {
  constructor(x, y, a, b) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
  toHash() {
    return `${this.x}::${this.y}::${this.a}::${this.b}`;
  }
}

class Buttons {
  constructor(...btns) {
    this.buttons = btns;
  }
  unique() {
    let set = new Set();
    let filtedBtns = [];
    this.buttons.forEach((btn) => {
      if (!set.has(btn.toHash())) {
        filtedBtns.push(btn);
        set.add(btn.toHash());
      }
    });
    this.buttons = filtedBtns;
  }
  deleteBtns(index) {
    this.buttons = this.buttons.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
  }
  deleteAll() {
    this.buttons = [];
  }
}
let playBtn = new Button(500, 650, 50, 100);
let tutorialBtn = new Button(500, 760, 110, 160);
let duplicateBtn = new Button(500, 760, 110, 160);
let scoreBtn = new Button(500, 670, 180, 230);
const btns = new Buttons(playBtn, tutorialBtn, duplicateBtn, scoreBtn);

console.log(btns.buttons);

btns.unique(); // update unique
console.log(btns.buttons);

btns.deleteBtns(1); // delete by index

console.log(btns.buttons);

btns.deleteAll(); // delete all
console.log(btns.buttons);
```

Comment: Problem is that I'm using buttons like this : ´function mouseClicked(e) {
    this.mouseX = e.pageX - neonWariorPlayArea.offsetX;
    this.mouseY = e.pageY - neonWariorPlayArea.offsetY;
    if (typeof playBtn != "undefined" && playBtn.clicked()) { drawModeSelect(); }}´ I don't know how to make it work with your code... sorry I'm new to js

Comment: you check my approach, i think you just need to update `toHash` function

Answer (score 0):

The `canvas` element on its own is just a bitmap and does not provide information about any drawn objects.  [src https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API]

You can not 'select' and then clear an object from canvas.
Instead use the `clearRect` method to clear the rectangular area from the canvas.

check stackblitz for a working sample
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-j81gxm?file=index.js

I have added two more properties to your button class

1. strokeWidth - stroke's width is always added to your rectangle's dimensions. e.g.: if your rectangle's width and and stroke is 1px then effective width of the rectangle becomes 1+100+1 = 102px. You can use strokeWidth property to set a variable strokeWidth and use it as reference for the `remove` function
2. Active button - to track if button is active for the click area

Introduced a `remove` method on the `button` class
This method will remove the rectangular area and mark the button inactive

`deleteBtns` function will filter out the buttons array while calling remove method for the individual button.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('app');

var neonWariorPlayArea = canvas.getContext("2d");
function button(xL, xR, yT, yB) {
    this.xLeft = xL;
    this.xRight = xR;
    this.yTop = yT;
    this.yBottom = yB;
    this.width = xR - xL;
    this.height = yB - yT;
    this.active = true;
    this.strokeWidth = 1;
    this.drawMe = function() {
        neonWariorPlayArea.strokeStyle = "green";
        neonWariorPlayArea.beginPath();
        neonWariorPlayArea.rect(this.xLeft, this.yTop, this.width, this.height);
        neonWariorPlayArea.stroke();
    }
}

button.prototype.clicked = function() {

    if (this.xLeft <= mouseX && mouseX <= this.xRight && this.yTop <= mouseY && mouseY <= this.yBottom && this.active ) {
        return true;

    }
}

button.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.active = false;
    neonWariorPlayArea.clearRect ( this.xLeft-this.strokeWidth, this.yTop-this.strokeWidth, this.width+this.strokeWidth*2, this.height+this.strokeWidth*2 );
}


var buttons = new Array();

const playBtn = new button(0, 50, 0, 50);
const tutorialBtn = new button(50, 100, 50, 100);
const scoreBtn = new button(100, 100, 50, 50);
playBtn.drawMe ();
tutorialBtn.drawMe ();
scoreBtn.drawMe ();
buttons.push(playBtn, tutorialBtn, scoreBtn);

function deleteBtns() {
    buttons = buttons.filter ( btn => {
      btn.remove ();
      return false;
    })
}
deleteBtns ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=350 height=180></canvas>
<script>
    function object(x, y, c) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = c
        this.draw = function () {
            context.fillStyle = this.color;
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(this.x, this.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
            context.fill();
        }
    }

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = draw;
    img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png";
    var objects = []
    objects.push(new object(200, 100, "blue"));
    objects.push(new object(250, 90, "cyan"));

    function draw() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        objects.forEach(o => o.draw());
    }

    canvas.onclick = function (e) {
        objects.push(new object(Math.random()*200, Math.random()*100, "red"));
        if (objects.length > 5)
            objects = objects.filter(o => o.color != "red");
        draw()
    }
</script>
```

Focus your attention on `function draw()`
That is called when the image is loaded an also for every click on the canvas.

On every draw we erase the entire canvas and draw it again, might sound like a lot but on modern browsers this happens so fast you do not see any flickers.

I created an array `objects = []` and on click I add a new object at a random location, on the forth click I remove all the red ones and new ones will be added on successive clicks.

---

There was a suggestion to just clear the rectangular section from the canvas but that would cause problem as you can see I also draw a background image, if I clear a section it could also clear the background, not the best behavior, and I'm sure your shapes will get more complex.

The key is to clear your entire canvas and draw everything again.

With that in mind, all you need to do on the event that triggers your delete just loop over your array and remove those don't need.